# Showing Schlaefli integral satisfies Legendre equation

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, legendre-polynomials

The integral representation of Legendre functions is $P_ν(z)=\frac{2^{-\nu}}{2\pi i} \oint_Γ\frac{(w^2−1)^\nu}{(w−z)^{\nu+1}} dw$. I'm trying to show that this satisfies Legendre's equation.

When I take the derivatives and plug it into the equation, I just get a nasty expression with nasty integrals times functions of z. I don't see how I can combine any of the terms, since they have different powers of z, and all the integrals look different.
$P'_ν(z)=\frac{2^{-\nu}}{2\pi i} \oint_Γ\frac{(w^2−1)^\nu(\nu+1)}{(w−z)^{\nu+2}} dw$
and
$P'_ν(z)=\frac{2^{-\nu}}{2\pi i} \oint_Γ\frac{(w^2−1)^\nu(\nu+1)(\nu+2)}{(w−z)^{\nu+3}} dw$
So the expression is
$$(1−z^2)\oint_Γ\frac{(w^2−1)^\nu(\nu+2)}{(w−z)^{\nu+3}} dw−2z \oint_Γ\frac{(w^2−1)^\nu}{(w−z)^{\nu+2}} dw+ν\oint_Γ\frac{(w^2−1)^\nu}{(w−z)^{\nu+1}} dw
$$
Where I factored out a $\frac{2^{-\nu}(\nu+1)}{2\pi i}$ from each of the terms.
Which I need to somehow show is equal to zero. I tried to collect all the integrals together, hoping they would combine together to give me a nice term. At first I was hoping it would give me $\frac{d}{dw}$ of the integrand, so I could just use Cauchy's theorem to show that the integral is zero. But the terms didn't seam to collect that way.

Oh and this integrand has branch points $\pm 1,z$, we take a cut between $-1$ and $-\infty$ along the negative real axis, and some cut between 1 and $z$. The contour $\Gamma$ is taken around a curve positively enclosing 1,$z$ (intersecting the real axis to the right of $-1$ as it must).

Answer (score 3):

The question contains the definition
\begin{equation*}
P_ν(z)=\frac{2^{-\nu}}{2\pi i} \oint_\Gamma \frac{(w^2−1)^\nu}{(w−z)^{\nu+1}} dw
\end{equation*}

Arfken$^1$, Ch12 Legendre Functions, Section 12.4 Alternate Definitions of Legendre Polynomials, gives, as part of (12.69), that

\begin{equation*}
P_n(z)=\frac{2^{-n}}{2\pi i} \oint \frac{(t^2−1)^n}{(t−z)^{n+1}} dt  \end{equation*}

and says that the contour encloses the point $t=z$.

The above integral for $P_n(z)$, is called the **Schlaefli integral**, here I use it for integers ‘n’, but it can be extended to non integral values of $P's$ index. A diagram should not really be required here, it’s such a simple idea. We have a closed contour in the complex t-plane, enclosing the point ‘z’.

Using $P_n(z)$ rather than $P_\nu(z)$ and substituting into Legendre's equation in the form

\begin{equation*}
(1-z^2)P_n^{\prime \prime}(z)-2zP_n^\prime(z) +n(n+1)P_n(z)=0
\end{equation*}
gives
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{A}&=(1-z^2)P_n^{\prime \prime}(z)-2zP_n^\prime(z) +n(n+1)P_n(z) \\
&=\frac{2^{-n}}{2\pi i} \oint 
\left[ [(1-z^2) \frac {d^2 }{dz^2 }  \frac {(t^2-1)^n }{ (t-z)^{n+1}} ]
-[2z\frac {d }{dz }  \frac {(t^2-1)^n }{ (t-z)^{n+1}}]
+[n(n+1)\frac {(t^2-1)^n }{ (t-z)^{n+1}}]\right]~dt
\end{align*}

Using
\begin{align*}
\frac {d }{dz }  \frac {(t^2-1)^n }{ (t-z)^{n+1}}&=\frac {d }{dz }  (t^2-1)^n  (t-z)^{-n-1}  \\
&=(-n-1)(t^2-1)^n  (t-z)^{-n-2} (-1) \\
&=\frac { (n+1)(t^2-1)^n}{ (t-z)^{n+2}} \\
\frac {d^2 }{dz^2 }  \frac {(t^2-1)^n }{ (t-z)^{n+1}}&=
\frac {d }{dz } \frac {d }{dz } \frac {(t^2-1)^n }{ (t-z)^{n+1}} \\
&=\frac { (n+1)(n+2)(t^2-1)^n}{ (t-z)^{n+3}} \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{A}=\frac{2^{-n}}{2\pi i} &\oint ( \left[\frac { (1-z^2)(n+1)(n+2)(t^2-1)^n}{ (t-z)^{n+3}}\right]  \\
&-~~\left[\frac {2z (n+1)(t^2-1)^n}{ (t-z)^{n+2}} \right] \\
&+~~\left[\frac {n (n+1)(t^2-1)^n}{ (t-z)^{n+1}} \right] )~dt\\
=\frac{2^{-n}}{2\pi i} &\oint \frac { (n+1)(t^2-1)^n}{ (t-z)^{n+3}}
\left[ ((n+2)(1-z^2))-2z(t-z)+n(t-z)^2   \right] ~dt
\end{align*}

Inside the square brackets we have
\begin{equation*}
(n+2-nz^2-2z^2)-(2zt-z^2)+(nt^2-2znt+nz^2)=nt^2-2znt-2zt+n+2\end{equation*}

**Hence, we have a main result**
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{A}=\frac{2^{-n}}{2\pi i}(n+1)\oint \frac { (t^2-1)^n}{ (t-z)^{n+3}}[nt^2-2znt-2zt+n+2]~dt \tag{1}
\end{equation*}

Now
\begin{align*}
\frac{ d}{dt }\left[   (t^2-1)^{n+1} (t-z)^{-n-2}      \right]&=[(n+1)(t^2-1)^n2t   ](t-z)^{-n-2} \\
&+(t^2-1)^{n+1}[-(n+2)(t-z)^{-n-3}] \\
&= \frac{(t^2-1)^n ~~~~}{(t-z)^{n+3} } [ ~[(n+1)2t(t-z)~]-[~(n+2)(t^2-1)~]  ~]\\
\end{align*}

Processing the symbols inside square brackets
\begin{align*}
[(n+1)2t(t-z)~]&=(n+1)(2t^2-2zt) =2nt^2+2t^2-2znt-2zt \\
-[~(n+2)(t^2-1)~] &=n+2-nt^2-2t^2
\end{align*}
Adding the right-hand sides of the above two equations, gives
\begin{equation*}
[nt^2-2znt-2zt+n+2]
\end{equation*}

So,
\begin{equation*}
\frac{d}{dt} \frac { (t^2-1)^{n+1}}{ (t-z)^{n+2}}=\frac { (t^2-1)^n}{ (t-z)^{n+3}}[nt^2-2znt-2zt+n+2]\end{equation*}

Hence, we can express $\mathbf{A}$, see the result in (1), as

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{A}=\frac{2^{-n}}{2\pi i}(n+1)\oint \frac{d}{dt} \left[  \frac { (t^2-1)^{n+1}}{ (t-z)^{n+2}}\right]~dt \tag{2}
\end{equation*}

Our $\mathbf{A}$, as given above, has the value zero. Upon completing a closed contour the function
\begin{equation*}
\frac { (t^2-1)^{n+1}}{ (t-z)^{n+2}}
\end{equation*}
returns to it's original value,and the integral is zero.

Knowing that $\mathbf{A}=0$, we may say that the function
\begin{equation*}
P_n(z)=\frac{2^{-n}}{2\pi i} \oint \frac{(t^2−1)^n}{(t−z)^{n+1}} dt  \end{equation*}

satisfies Legendre's equation,
\begin{equation*}
(1-z^2)P_n^{\prime \prime}(z)-2zP_n^\prime(z) +n(n+1)P_n(z)=0
\end{equation*}

The Schlaefli integral, satisfies Legendre’s equation.

Reference:

1, George Arfken, Mathematical Methods For Physicists, Second Edition, Academic Press (1970).

Comment: Great and clear answer. A pleasure to read. However, concerning the case where $n$ is not an integer, then the curve goes through a branch cut since it encircles $t=z$ and it is not clear that ${\bf{A}}=0$. How would that work then?

Comment: @Gateau au fromage  If a contour encircles a point $t=z$, this does not mean that it also goes through some cut-line. The contour used to define $P_\nu(z), \nu$ not a integer, according to Arfken$^1$, encircles the point $t=z$ and the singular point $t=1$, but does not cross a cut-line from -1 to -$\infty$. Exactly how this would make $\mathbf{A}$ equal zero, I do not know.

Comment: @Gateau au fromage  I have just noticed that Arfken$^1$, uses a cut-line from $t=1$ to $t=z$ for defining $P_\nu(z)$, as well as one from from $t=-1$ to -$\infty$. So it looks like, merely encircling the point $t=z$ and the point $t=1$ without crossing any cut-lines, means that, even for non-integer $n$

\begin{equation*}
\frac { (t^2-1)^{n+1}}{ (t-z)^{n+2}}
\end{equation*}

would return to it's original value, after completing the closed contour in the definition of $P_\nu(z)$ and $\mathbf{A}=0$.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand.

Comment: I wish I did, ... maybe next week?

Comment: Seriously though, I am working on trying to understand what's involved.

Comment: Maybe there is something I don't see but your answer is clear. What is left to understand? The only issue perhaps is to choose the contour correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, if you put in $(1-z^2) = -(w^2-1) + 2w(w-z) - (w-z)^2$ and $z = w -(w-z)$ and do the algebra, it comes to $ \frac{d}{dw} \Big[ \frac{(w^2-1)^{\nu+1}}{(w-z)^{\nu+2}}\Big]$ so you can evaluate the integral, by evaluating $\frac{(w^2-1)^{\nu+1}}{(w-z)^{\nu+2}}$ around $\Gamma$ but it is a closed curve so it must vanish. I think that proves it, any thoughts?

Comment: Is this answer nonsense?

Answer (score 0):

For non-integral ‘$\nu$’, substituting the Schlaefli integral form of the function $P_\nu(z)$

\begin{equation*}
P_\nu(z)=\frac{2^{-\nu}}{2\pi i} \oint_Γ\frac{(t^2−1)^\nu}{(t−z)^{\nu+1}} dt  \tag{1}
\end{equation*}

into the left-hand side of Legendre’s equation

\begin{equation*}
(1-z^2)P_\nu^{\prime \prime}(z)-2zP_\nu^\prime(z) +\nu(\nu+1)P_\nu(z)=0  \tag{2}
\end{equation*}

would lead to

\begin{align*}
&(1-z^2)P_\nu^{\prime \prime}(z)-2zP_\nu^\prime(z) +\nu(\nu+1)P_\nu(z)\\
=&\frac{2^{-\nu}}{2\pi i}(\nu+1)\oint_\Gamma  \frac { (t^2-1)^\nu}{ (t-z)^{\nu+3}}[\nu t^2-2z\nu t-2zt+\nu+2]~dt  \\
=&\frac{2^{-\nu}}{2\pi i}(\nu+1)\oint_\Gamma \frac{d}{dt} \left[  \frac { (t^2-1)^{\nu+1}}{ (t-z)^{\nu+2}}\right]~dt \tag{3}
\end{align*}

Call the right-hand side of (3), $\mathbf{\tilde{A}}$

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{\tilde{A}}=\frac{2^{-\nu}}{2\pi i}(\nu+1)\oint_\Gamma \frac{d}{dt} \left[  \frac { (t^2-1)^{\nu+1}}{ (t-z)^{\nu+2}}\right]~dt \tag{4}
\end{equation*}

If, $\mathbf{\tilde{A}}=0$, then the Sclaefli integral satisfies the Legendre equation.

See my first answer, to this question,  dated Oct 7 2022,
[Showing Schlaefli integral satisfies Legendre equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935345/showing-schlaefli-integral-satisfies-legendre-equation/4547463#4547463) .
There I analyse, starting with $P_n(z)$ not $P_\nu(z)$, but the derivations can easily be adapted, changing  ‘$n$’s to ‘$\nu$’s in the math, should do the trick, but only up to (2), after which there is material on $\mathbf{A}=0$. See (1) and (2)  in particular.

For $\mathbf{\tilde{A}}$ to equal zero, we must have, for the multi-valued function
$(t^2-1)^{\nu+1}/ (t-z)^{\nu+2}$

\begin{equation*}
\left[  \frac { (t^2-1)^{\nu+1}}{ (t-z)^{\nu+2}}\right]_{t_1}^{t_2}=0
\end{equation*}
where $t_1$ is considered the start of $\Gamma=\Gamma_1$, i.e. the start of our chosen contour, and $t_2$ is the end point of the same contour.

[[image: The Contour <span class=]$\Gamma_1$." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHsKL.png)

There is now described an Arfken$^1$ type closed contour, called $\Gamma_1$, which lies in the complex t-plane.

The t-plane contains a particular point called $z$, placed in the upper right quadrant. Special points are $t=+1$, $t=-1$, $t=z$. There are two cut-lines, the first from $t=1$ to $t=z$, the second from $t=-1$ to $t=-\infty$.

The closed contour $\Gamma_1$, encircles both the points $t=z$ and $t=+1$, but does not cross either of the two cut-lines. Hence the cut-line from $t=+1$ to $t=z$ is completely enclosed by $\Gamma_1$

The contour $\Gamma_1$ does not cross any cut-lines, hence it looks as if $t_2$ is the same point as $t_1$. It looks as if, it is not on some other sheet of a multi-sheeted construct. So we have, $\mathbf{ \tilde{A}}=0$.

Knowing that $\mathbf{ \tilde{A}}=0$  we may say that the function

\begin{equation*}
P_\nu(z)=\frac{2^{-\nu}}{2\pi i} \oint_Γ\frac{(t^2−1)^\nu}{(t−z)^{\nu+1}} dt  
\end{equation*}

satisfies Legendre’s equation

\begin{equation*}
(1-z^2)P_\nu^{\prime \prime}(z)-2zP_\nu^\prime(z) +\nu(\nu+1)P_\nu(z)=0  
\end{equation*}

The Schlaefli integral, satisfies Legendre’s equation.

**Reference**

1, George Arfken, Mathematical Methods For Physicists, Second Edition, Academic Press (1970). See Ch12 Legendre Functions, Section 12.4 Alternate Definitions of Legendre Polynomials, Fig12.9.