# Should Hobson, pg183, be corrected, in particular, should an occurrence of $(t^2−1)^n(t−\mu)^{-n-m-1}$ be replaced by $(t^2−1)^{n+1}(t−\mu)^{-n-m-2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, legendre-functions

The material in this question concerns substitution of a Schlaefli type integral into a differential equation. My answer to the question  [Showing Schlaefli integral satisfies Legendre equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935345/showing-schlaefli-integral-satisfies-legendre-equation/4547463#4547463)
should inform the interested reader.

Hobson$^1$, pg 183, tells us, that if we substitute

> \begin{equation*} \nu= \int (t^2−1)^n(t−\mu)^{-n-m-1} ~dt  
>  \end{equation*}

into the left-hand side ( LHS ) of an equation labelled (3) from Hobson$^1$ pg 180, which is actually a transformed form of ‘Legendre’s Associated Equation’, see below

> \begin{equation*} (1-\mu^2) \frac{ d^2 \nu  }{ d\mu^2  } -2(m+1)\mu  
>  \frac{ d \nu  }{ d\mu  } +(n-m)(n+m+1)\nu = 0         \tag{3}     
>  \end{equation*}

we should find that (a quote from p183),

> \begin{align*} \left\{  (1-\mu^2) \frac{ d^2   }{ d\mu^2  } -2(m+1)\mu
>  \frac{ d }{ d\mu  } +(n-m)(n+m+1)                   \right\}  \int
>  (t^2−1)^n(t−\mu)^{-n-m-1} ~dt \\
>  =-(n+m+1)\int \frac{d}{dt} \left\{  (t^2-1)^{n+1} (t-\mu)^{-n-m-2}\right\}~dt \end{align*}

Please note I have doubts about the minus sign at the beginning of the left-hand side above.

Hobson$^1$ then says that, quote

> It thus appears that the differential equation (3) is satisfied by
> \begin{equation*} \nu= \int (t^2−1)^n(t−\mu)^{-n-m-1} ~dt  
>  \end{equation*} for unrestricted values of n and m, provided the
> integration is taken along a closed path of such a character that the
> integrand attains the same value, when the path has been completely
> described, as that with which it began. The integrand has, in general,
> the four singular points $t=1, t=-1, t=\mu, t=\infty $; a closed curve
> which contains in its interior one or more of these singular points
> will, in general, be such that the integrand attains a value after a
> complete description of the closed curve different from its initial
> value. The closed paths for which this is not the case , and which can
> therefore be employed to define an integral of the differential
> equation, may be characterized as being closed when drawn on the
> Riemann’s surface on which the function $(t^2−1)^n(t−\mu)^{-n-m-1},
>  ~of~t$, is represented as a single-valued function.

My question is: Should in the last sentence above,

\begin{equation*}
(t^2−1)^n(t−\mu)^{-n-m-1}
 \end{equation*}

be replaced by
\begin{equation*}
~~~~~~~(t^2−1)^{n+1}(t−\mu)^{-n-m-2}~~?
 \end{equation*}

**Other**

It also looks as if, in the large textual quote from Hobson$^1$, that

“such a character that the integrand attains the same value”

should be replaced by, something like,

“such a character that $(t^2−1)^{n+1}(t−\mu)^{-n-m-2}$ attains the same value”.

Perhaps other corrections might be needed?

As an extra, could anyone provide a reference to material on how to work out what the ‘Riemann Surface’, for $(t^2−1)^{n+1}(t−\mu)^{-n-m-2}$, actually is, or to material on working out Riemann surfaces in general?

**Other:This is prompted by a comment by ”Gateau au fromage”, from 11th Oct 2022.**

The closed curve used by Hobson$^1$, starting on pg183, to define the function $\nu$ is a complicated four loop thing. We may take there to be two essentially different loops, each traversed both clock-wise and anticlock-wise. One of the loops encloses the point $t=\mu$, the other encloses the point $t=1$. It is explained on pg 188 that the defining contour integral for ‘Legendre’s Associated Function Of The First Kind $P_n^m(\mu)$’, which is related to the function $\nu$, uses what he calls a ‘Cross-Cut’ from the point $t=+1$ to $t=- \infty$, so the two loopings enclosing $t=1$ used in the definition of $\nu$ should cross this cut-line once.

I guess that this  ensures

1. that the function

\begin{equation*}
\frac { (t^2-1)^{n+1}}{ ~~~(t-\mu)^{n+m+2}}
\end{equation*}

returns to the value that it had at the start of the contour, when the contour is completed,

and that

2. our function ‘$\nu$’ can have non-zero values.

**Reference**

1, E.W.Hobson, The Theory of Spherical and Ellipsoidal Harmonics, Cambridge University Press, 1931.

Comment: In the text, the closed curve is defined as not containing $\mu$, $\pm 1$, and $\infty$, so, as a consequence I believe, it is a closed curve on the Riemann's surface of the two fcts (the one of the book and the one you mention). So, I don't read that text as saying that the curve is defined as a closed curve on the Riemann's surface. What I don't understand is that, with such a curve, $v$ itself is zero, so it does not seem to define a solution.